# JSON Schema Conditional Required - If not null & has certain value

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I have a pretty simple requirement:

If vehicleType IS NOT NULL, AND vehicleType IS CAR then topSpeed is required, else, topSpeed is not required.

Currently, if vehicleType (which is optional), is not provided, must have required property 'topSpeed' error is happening.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is a snippet of the JSON Schema:

```
"vehicle": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "valuation": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "vehicleType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["Car", "Airplane", "Boat", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
      },
      "topSpeed": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    },

    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "vehicleType": {
          "const": "Car"
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": ["topSpeed"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` schema is true because vehicleType is not required. Therefore the `then` branch is applied even if vehicleType is not present. Add `"required": [ "vehicleType" ]` to the `if` schema.

[image]